# Capturar datos de una tabla html con jquery y enviarlos a un servlet

Tags: javascript, java, sql, jsp

Estimados solicito por favor su apoyo para resolver un problema.
estoy trabajando en una aplicación y necesito ver la forma de capturar los datos de una tabla html con registros que viene  de otra tabla con registros pero no puedo realizarlo ya que ambas tablas estan en distintos formularios y no se como enviar los datos desde la segunda tabla.

Primera tabla.
Esta tabla recibe datos desde una base de datos mysqlk a traves de un servlet por medio de sesiones.

```
<form method="POST" action="">

                <table class="table table-hover" border="1" id="tabla1">
                   <tbody>
                   <tr id="a1">

                       <th>Awb</th>
                       <th>Origen</th>
                       <th>Destino</th>
                       <th>Piezas</th>
                       <th>Kilos</th>
                       <th>Volumen</th>
                       <th>Id Vuelo</th>
                       <th>Tramo</th>
                       <th>Mover</th>

                   </tr>

<% 

try
{
    for(int i=0; i<guia.size(); i++)
           {
                        out.println("<tr id='a2'>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getNumeroGuia()+"</td>");

                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getOrigenGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getDestinoGuia()+"</td>");
                        //out.println("<td>"+guia.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"</td>");

                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getPiezasGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getKilosGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getVolumenGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getIdVueloGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getIdTramoGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'><input type='checkbox' size=5 name='txt_idvuelo_guia' class='form-control' value='"+guia.get(i).getIdVueloGuia()+"'></td>");

           }     

}
catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
{
    out.println("</tr>");

}

%>

</tbody>
               </table>
           </form>
```

Esta tabla por medio de una función de javascript, le traspasa las columnas con los datos a otra tabla html.

Aqui codigo javascript.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        // el checkbox esta marcado
        // movemos la columna a la tabla2
        var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#tabla2 tbody");
    }else{
        // el checkbox esta desmarcado
        // movemos la columna a la tabla1
        var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#tabla1 tbody");
    }
});



});

</script>
```

Acá la segunda tabla , esta recibe las columnas con los datos de la tabla anterior.

```
<form method="POST" action="movimientosCargaMoverCargaServlet.do">
               <!--<div class="table-responsive">-->
                <table class="table table-hover col-sm-6" border="1" id="tabla2">
                   <tbody>
                   <tr>

                       <th>Awb</th>
                       <th>Origen</th>
                       <th>Destino</th>
                       <th>Piezas</th>
                       <th>Kilos</th>
                       <th>Volumen</th>
                       <th>Id Vuelo</th>
                       <th>Tramo</th>
                       <th>Acción</th>
                   </tr>

                </tbody>  
               </table>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Asignar">
<input type="resert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Limpiar">


</form>
```

La segunda tabla tiene un botón que se llama Asignar, con este botón quiero enviar unos parametros a un servlet para ejecutar, pero como las columnas que se mueven a la segunda tabla , se mueven de manera visual con javascript ya que la segunda tabla no tiene definidas las columnas en codigo, al presionar el botón Asignar me da un error e indica valores nulos.

Aquí el servlet que debería recibir los datos.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    Vuelo vuelo1=new Vuelo();
    Folio f=new Folio();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection con=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
    GuiasDao gdao = new GuiasDao();
    ArrayList<Guia> guia = new ArrayList<Guia>();
    Guia g=new Guia();

    vuelo1.setIdVuelo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txt_id_vuelo_disp")));
    g.setNumeroGuia((request.getParameter("txt_guia")));
    guia.add(g);
PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement)gdao.moverCarga(vuelo1, g);
    for(int i=0;i<g.getNumeroGuia().length();i++)
    {
    out.println(guia.get(i).getNumeroGuia());

   try {

    if(request.getParameter("txt_id_vuelo_disp").isEmpty()&& request.getParameter("txt_guia").isEmpty())
    {
       /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<link rel='stylesheet href=bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'>");
        out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>");
        out.println("<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Mover carga</title>");           
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("<form>");
        out.println("<div class='form-row'>");

        out.println("<p> Error </p>");

    }
    else
    {
        out.println("<p> Registro Actualizado con exito </p>");
        out.println("<p> se ha asignado el vuelo :'"+vuelo1.getIdVuelo()+"'</p>");
        out.println("<p> Las guias afectadas son:'"+guia.get(i).getNumeroGuia()+"'</p>");
    }

        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</form>"); 

    }
    catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        out.println("<h1>'"+ex.getMessage()+"'</h1>");
    }
    finally {

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
   }
}
```

los campos de texto "**txt_id_vuelo_rvdisponibles**" y "**txt_id_vuelo_rvdisponibles**" los tomo de otras tablas que están en otros formularios.

acá el código de la clase GuiasDao que es la que tiene la sentencia sql que deseo ejecutar.

```
public ResultSet moverCarga(Vuelo v1,Vuelo v2)
{
    try {
        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
        //st=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
        pst=(PreparedStatement)conn.createStatement();
        String SQLUpdate="";

        SQLUpdate="UPDATE tvas t\n" +
                  "INNER JOIN rvas r\n" +
                  "ON(t.rvas_cod_seq_rvas = r.cod_seq_rvas)\n" +
                  "SET t.vlos_seq_vlos = '"+v1.getIdVuelo()+"'\n" +
                  "WHERE t.vlos_seq_vlos = '"+v2.getIdVuelo()+"';";;
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(SQLUpdate);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GuiasDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    return res;
}
```

acá una imagen de como es el proceso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Aquí la imagen del resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimados me podrían ayudar por favor.

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolverlo ?

Comment: No , estuve intentando hacerlo con jsp para no tener que usar otro leguaje, pero tampoco he podido.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código del botón que envía la tabla ?

Comment: lo voy a agregar

Comment: ahí los agregue, me habían faltado en el ultimo formulario que agregue cuando cree esta pregunta

Comment: el botón se llama Asignar

Comment: lo que necesito es que al hacer click con el checkbox, al presionar asignar, este me capture el dato del registro seleccionado con el check box, y si selecciono varios registros, estos se capturen separados por comas, para así ejecutarlos todos en la sentencia SQL.

Comment: Pero, estas seguro que al dar click a Asignar llega a al servidor ?

Comment: si llega y me actualiza pero siempre el primer registro y no el que selecciono con el check box ya que tengo otra versión, una que usa un campo de texto en la tabla para capturar el dato, mas tarde subiré el código de esa versión para que lo veas.

Comment: ahí está el código completo